# Can't get 100% height to work (read most posts here and tried for 1+ hours)

Tags: height, css

Sorry to bother with such a *beginner's question* but I simply can't get this 100% height thing to work. Here is the situation (sorry, developing locally so no link):

I have a wrapping container that contains two floating elements. I followed all steps that might resolve the 100% issue, such as:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  background: url(../img/bg.png);
  font-family: 'SansationRegular', Helvetica;
}

.wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  height: auto !important; (apparently this fixes the issue in Chrome)
  margin:40px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding:0;
}
```

Both floating div's (sidebar and content) have height: 100% and I also added a third div container to clear the floating elements.

Still, when I add content to the content div the sidebar does not "grow" automatically. I feel I tried everything but it won't work.

Any ideas/hints are highly appreciated at this point! :)

Many thanks in advance!

P.S. I use Twitter Bootstrap as well in case that helps to solve my problem

Comment: I can't help you without seeing relevant code.  Please provide all 
the HTML and CSS to demonstrate the problem, but without anything irrelevant.

Comment: If you have a live link, that would help the most. Especially for something like this.

Comment: Did you use height : 100vh instead of height: 100% css property.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic example which shows how to do what you're trying to do. You should be able to take this code and adapt it to your own code.

http://jsfiddle.net/QXZuy/1/

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="sidebar"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>


html, body {
  height:100%;
}
.wrap {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  display:table;
  overflow:auto;
  background:#ccc;
}
.sidebar {
  display:table-cell;
  width:25%;
  background-color:blue;
}
.content {
  display:table-cell;
  width:75%;
  background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Billy Moat. I tried this already but as soon as the content grows longer than the initial screen size it won't work anymore. At least in my case..

Comment: @domdev - I've amended my answer to use a different method. Have a look and see if that works for you...

Comment: Thanks Billy! I tried all CSS tricks but couldn't get it to work. I decided to go with a bit of jQuery and it works like a charm (see below). Thank you a lot for your help though!